# Validar campos com html 5 e mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Como eu valido campos no próprio CSHTML, que quando eu clicar no botão, ele valide os campos e caso haja campos não preenchido ele permanece na página, exibindo uma mensagem. Veja os campos de exemplo e o botão para validar.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="grid_4">
        <label>Nome</label>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_14">
        <input type="text" name="txtNome" class="grid_14 required" placeholder="Nome completo" required />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="grid_4">
        <label>Email</label>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_7">
        <input type="email" name="txtEmail" class="grid_6  required" placeholder="Email válido" required />
    </div>
    <div class="grid_2">
        <label>CPF</label>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_5">
        <input type="number" name="txtCpf" class="grid_5  required" placeholder="99999999999" required />
    </div>
</div>

//Botão

<div class="grid_17">
    <button value="novaPesquisa" class="btn-pular-passo pull-right">Continuar</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

No [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc), a validação é feita decorando as propriedades do seu `Model` com os atributos adequados.

Exemplos:

- `[Required]`: Torna a propriedade de preenchimento obrigatório.
- `[StringLength(60)]`: Faz a propriedade `String` ter no máximo 60 caracteres.

Para que as validações funcionem adequadamente, é preciso usar o seguinte código em Razor logo após o `<input>` da sua propriedade:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SuaProperty)
```

Comment: Tentei assim, mas no Helper do Razor não funciona. Preciso adicionar algum using? Só uma pergunta. O required não deveria travar se o campo estivesse vazio? Meu botão chamando outra página, por exemplo, caso tenha campo vazio não deveria travar? E se o botão apenas habilita uma div, que é meu caso, como eu faria para travar?

Answer (score 2):

O que você esta querendo não é a bibliioteca Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Validation? Adicione ela via NuGet.

Habilite no web.config e teste.

No web.config é essa propriedade que precisa habilitar:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Eu até tentei aqui também, mas na hora de instalar ela deu erro de incompatibilidade com jQuery. Mesmo desinstalando o jQuery e instalando ele, deixando então que ele resolva a dependência do jQuery, ainda assim deu problema.

Então, se der problema remova o jQuery, instale primeiro o jQuery Validation e ai então instale o Microoft jQuery Unobtrusive Validation.

Isso aqui pra mim resolveu a incompatibilidade.

**EDIÇÃO**

Não se esqueça de adicionar os plugins jQuery Validation na View.
Para seguir o padrão você precisa adicioná-los no BundleConfig.cs dentro da pasta App_Start.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/js/jqueryval").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.*"));
```

E depois adicionar na view a chamada à esses scripts:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/js/jqueryval")
```

Feito isso tem que funcionar.

Comment: Já estão habilitadas.

Comment: Adicionou a biblioteca?